# biblatex: Change formatting of back references

Tags: biblatex

When using back references, `biblatex-chicago` formats bibliography entries as "author, year, title. (Cited on page x)."

[image]

Given that the back reference follows a period, it makes no sense to me that there's a period *following* the closing parenthesis. Instead, I think it should appear *before* the closing parenthesis, i.e. "author, year, title. (Cited on page x.)"

How can I change this? (I did not find any suitable options to change the formatting in the `biblatex` or `biblatex-chicago` documentations.)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[authordate,backref=true]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{refs.bib}
  @book{somebook,
    author={some author},
    title={some title},
    date={2021}
  }
\end{filecontents}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  backrefpage = {cited on page}
}

\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\begin{refsection}
\textcite{somebook} showed that...
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: I changed the title of my question from `biblatex-chicago` to `biblatex` because I later realised that what I wanted to change had nothing to do with `biblatex-chicago`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this we need two things. First of all we have to eliminate the final point. This can be done simply with

```
\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{}
```

Then we must put the period before the closing parenthesis. This is less straightforward (as far as I know), as the `pageref` list format has a complex definition. So we define a new format, `backrefpage`, and then we modify the `pageref` macro thanks to the `xpatch` package:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\DeclareFieldFormat{backrefparens}{\mkbibparens{#1\addperiod}}
\xpatchbibmacro{pageref}{parens}{backrefparens}{}{}
```

You can achieve the same result with this:

```
\DeclareListWrapperFormat*{pageref}{#1\addperiod}
```

However it seems to me a less correct solution (from a logical point of view).

Comment: Thank you. For posterity, it might be good if you could amend your answer by stating that the `\DeclareFieldFormat` and `\xpatchbibmacro` need to go into the body of the document.

Comment: No, those two commands go into the preamble, but he mistake was mine...
Sorry, I forgot the last two empty groups in `\xpatchbibmarco` command (`{}{}`). I have corrected the answer.