# How to modify backref format in biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, back-referencing

Trying to get backref to work with biblatex with KOMA, I came up with the following code:

```
 \documentclass{scrbook}
 
 \usepackage[natbib=true,backref=true,style=ieee]{biblatex}
 
 \usepackage{hyperref} \addbibresource{sample.bib}
 
 \DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{   backrefpage={See p.},  
 backrefpages={See pp.} }
 
 
 \begin{document}
 
 \chapter{Chap 1} Some text\cite{greenwade93}. 
 
 
 \printbibliography
 
 \end{document}
```

where `DefineBibliography` allows me to modify how the citation reads. Going from

```
 . D. Greenwade, “The Comprehensive Tex Archive Network (CTAN),”TUGBoat,vol. 14, no. 3, pp. 342–351, 1993 (Cit. on p. 1).
```

to

```
 . D. Greenwade, “The Comprehensive Tex Archive Network (CTAN),”TUGBoat,vol. 14, no. 3, pp. 342–351, 1993 (see p. 1).
```

But how do I remove the parentheses in between `(see p. 1)`? Or how do I modify the formatting further so that the numbers become superscripts with nothing else for example? I cannot find it in the [manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following solution was inspired by [biblatex: Change formatting of back references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/578989/biblatex-change-formatting-of-back-references). To add a period following the reference and before the backref citation, include an `\addperiod` in the `\DeclareFieldFormat` command.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[natbib=true,backref=true,style=ieee]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{sample.bib} 
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  %  backrefpage={see p.},
  backrefpage={},
  %  backrefpages={see pp.}
  backrefpages={}
}
\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{}
\usepackage{xpatch}
%\DeclareFieldFormat{backrefparens}{\mkbibparens{#1\addperiod}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{backrefparens}{\addperiod\raisebox{4pt}{\scriptsize{#1}}}
\xpatchbibmacro{pageref}{parens}{backrefparens}{}{}
 
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chap 1}
Some text\cite{greenwade93}.
\newpage
Some text\cite{greenwade93}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I add a period at the end of each bibliography item before the backref citation such that it appears `D. Greenwade, “The Comprehensive Tex Archive Network (CTAN),”TUGBoat,vol. 14, no. 3, pp. 342–351, 1993. (see p. 1)`?