Add condition to enable a backref customization on the basis of an option in biblatex
I want to configure a conditional setup on the bibliography such that when the option backref=true is used, it should appear as:

[1] Vladimir I Arnold. Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics. Vol. 60. Graduate Texts in Mathematics. Springer Science & Business Media, 2013. (p. 2)

If backref=true is commented out or not enabled (default behavior):

[1] Vladimir I Arnold. Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics. Vol. 60. Graduate Texts in Mathematics. Springer Science & Business Media, 2013.

Here's my MWE:
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={black},
    citecolor={black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black},
}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

% bibliography
\usepackage[
    backend=biber, 
    backref=true, 
    style=numeric, 
    sortcites=true, 
    sorting=none, 
    defernumbers=true
]{biblatex}       
\usepackage{xurl}               

%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/606518/114006
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
   backrefpage={p.},
   backrefpages={pp.}
}
\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{} % Need to apply the condition here.
\usepackage{xpatch}

\DeclareFieldFormat{backrefparens}{\addperiod~\raisebox{-4pt}{\scriptsize{\mkbibparens{#1}}}}
\xpatchbibmacro{pageref}{parens}{backrefparens}{}{}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib}
@book{arnold2013mathematical,
  title = {Mathematical {{Methods}} of {{Classical Mechanics}}},
  author = {Arnold, Vladimir I},
  date = {2013},
  series = {Graduate {{Texts}} in {{Mathematics}}},
  volume = {60},
  publisher = {{Springer Science \& Business Media}}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{ref.bib} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\cite{arnold2013mathematical}  

\printbibliography

\end{document}



The following does not technically work by taking into account the backref option setting (which would be difficult, because options are processed in a way that makes the final value not available in the preamble), but instead modifies the pageref bibmacro so that it sets \finentrypunct to empty if appropriate.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=numeric,
  sortcites=true,
  sorting=none,
  defernumbers=true,
  backref=true,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xurl}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks,
  linkcolor={black},
  citecolor={black},
  urlcolor={blue!80!black},
}

%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/606518/114006
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  backrefpage  = {p\adddot},
  backrefpages = {pp\adddot},
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{backrefparens}{\raisebox{-4pt}{\scriptsize{\mkbibparens{#1}}}}
\renewbibmacro*{pageref}{%
  \iflistundef{pageref}
    {}
    {\setunit{\finentrypunct\addnbspace}%
     \printtext[backrefparens]{%
       \ifnumgreater{\value{pageref}}{1}
         {\bibstring{backrefpages}\ppspace}
         {\bibstring{backrefpage}\ppspace}%
       \printlist[pageref][-\value{listtotal}]{pageref}}%
     \renewcommand\finentrypunct{}}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\nocite{worman}

\printbibliography
\end{document}



Thank you. Why did you prefer using p\adddot instead of p.?

@raf If we write p. biblatex thinks the . is a sentence-ending full stop/period. If we write p\adddot, biblatex knows it is a dot that marks an abbreviation. This is important for the punctuation tracking feature where we can have dot-comma, but not full stop-comma etc.

Thank you for the clarification!

I have found a way to tackle the condition using \ifbacktracker. I am getting the desired output. Also, I get the default behavior when I remove the option backref=true.
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={black},
    citecolor={black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black},
}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber, 
    style=numeric, 
    sortcites=true, 
    sorting=none, 
    defernumbers=true,
    backref=true,
]{biblatex}       
\usepackage{xurl}               

%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/606518/114006
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
   backrefpage={p.},
   backrefpages={pp.}
}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\ifbacktracker
    \renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{}
    \DeclareFieldFormat{backrefparens}{\addperiod\raisebox{-4pt}{\scriptsize{\mkbibparens{#1}}}}
    \xpatchbibmacro{pageref}{parens}{backrefparens}{}{}
\fi 

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\cite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography

\end{document}


Checking the answer of @moewe, I found a problem with this answer. It's affecting the behavior of \nocite command. When backref=true is used, \nocite should also show the default punctuation (period) at the end of each bib entry, but it's not showing.

This will also run into trouble if you later in the preamble do \ExecuteBibliographyOptions{backref=false} or if per-type or per-entry options are used.

I see... I'd better go with your solution.
